# trying to upload video using graph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have been trying to implement a video upload facebook feature for my mobile app for a while now but never really succeeded with rest. I learnt yesterday that the graph alternative was available.

After getting a few errors to do with access key mainly i have gotten to the point where output stream succesfully writes the movie file and the input stream just receives an empty json array once i have written the 3gp file.

Anyone any idea why I would get an empty json array and no video gets published when i get all my code to run, i get 200 response code and the server sends me a non error response?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Here is the class that gets the blank json array (send method). I have appended the token to the url and in the table to be sure. I am sorry if the code is untidy buts it just been a day of trial and error.

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import javax.microedition.io.Connector;
import javax.microedition.io.HttpConnection;
import net.rim.device.api.io.http.HttpProtocolConstants;

public class HttpMultipartRequest2
{
    static final String BOUNDARY = "----------V2ymHFg03ehbqgZCaKO6jy";
    byte[] postBytes = null;
    String url = null;
    Hashtable paramsTable;

```
public HttpMultipartRequest2(String url, Hashtable params,
        String fileField, String fileName, String fileType, byte[] fileBytes) throws Exception
{
    this.url = url;

    String boundary = getBoundaryString();
    paramsTable = params;
    String boundaryMessage = getBoundaryMessage(boundary, params, fileField, fileName, fileType);
    String endBoundary = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n";
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bos.write(boundaryMessage.getBytes());
    bos.write(fileBytes);
    bos.write(endBoundary.getBytes());
    this.postBytes = bos.toByteArray();
    bos.close();
}
String getBoundaryString()  {
    return BOUNDARY;
}

String getBoundaryMessage(String boundary, Hashtable params, String fileField, String fileName, String fileType)
{
    StringBuffer res = new StringBuffer("--").append(boundary).append("\r\n");
    Enumeration keys = params.keys();
    while(keys.hasMoreElements())
    {
        String key = (String)keys.nextElement();
        String value = (String)params.get(key);
        res.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"").append(key).append("\"\r\n")
                .append("\r\n").append(value).append("\r\n")
                .append("--").append(boundary).append("\r\n");
    }
    res.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"").append(fileField)
            .append("\"; filename=\"").append(fileName).append("\"\r\n")
            .append("Content-Type: ").append(fileType).append("\r\n\r\n");
    Log.info(("res "+res.toString()));
    return res.toString();
}

public String send() throws Exception
{
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    HttpConnection hc = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] res = null;
    try
    {
        Log.info("before hc open"+ url);
        hc = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url);
        hc.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + getBoundaryString());
        hc.setRequestProperty("access_token", (String)paramsTable.get("access_token"));
        hc.setRequestProperty(HttpProtocolConstants.HEADER_CONTENT_LENGTH, String.valueOf(postBytes.length));
        hc.setRequestProperty( "x-rim-transcode-content", "none" );
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        OutputStream dos = hc.openOutputStream();
         is = hc.openInputStream();
           Log.info("before  dos write responsecode");// + hc.getResponseCode());
        out.write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.length);
         //Log.info("flushing"+ hc.getResponseCode());
        Log.info("after  doswrite responsecode");

              dos.write(out.toByteArray());

              dos.flush();
                     Log.info("after flush");
                    if(dos!=null)
                            dos.close();
        int ch;
         Log.info("before openinput ");

           Log.info("after openinput ");
        while ((ch = is.read()) != -1)
        {
            bos.write(ch);
            sb.append((char)ch);
               Log.info("char"+(char)ch);
        }
        res = bos.toByteArray();
          Log.info("Response recieved from Server is : " + sb.toString() );

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.info(hc.getResponseCode() + "sexce"+e);
    }
    catch(OutOfMemoryError error)
            {
                    Log.info("outofmemory " + error);
                  System.gc();
            }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            if(bos != null)
                bos.close();
            if(is != null)
                is.close();
            if(hc != null)
                hc.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e2)
        {
           Log.info("finally exception"+ e2);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to upload to a user's feed or to a page?  There is an [Open Bug](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=17084) regarding posting to pages.

Also, could you post some code?

Assuming that you've read the documentation:

[Facebook Graph API->Video](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/video/)

And that you are using `graph-video.facebook.com`, not `graph.facebook.com`.

Comment: I just want to post to a users wall. I am def using the graph video url. I have read the documentation for video upload in graph api many times but still getting a blank json array. How would i post code here? It tells me i have minus 3000 characters left. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I just tried the PHP example from the Facebook docs and it works.  I get back json with the id of the new object on the graph:  
`{
   "id": "10150196443143217"
}`
I'm not a java expert but I don't see anything wrong with the code at first glance.  However, the url you are passing in is quite important.  Can you share that?

Comment: hi, im just calling the api like this ..     String url = "https://graph-video.facebook.com/me/videos" +"?description=testdesc&title=testtitle&access_token="+app.fbc.graph.getAccessToken()+ getConnectionProfile();

Comment: Two suggestions.  First, I don't see where you declare `Connector`, used in `Connector.open(url)`.  I have a suspicion you are using http instead of https.  Second, before diving into code, get your URLs working by using something like `curl` or [Simon Cross' Graph Explorer](https://www.simoncross.com/fb/graph/).

Comment: Also noticed you have a semicolon at the end of `.../videos";`.  You sure that should be there?

Comment: Hi Todd, i see what you mean about the colon but it doesn't seem to be in code so prob a typo. You were right that i was using httpConnection in stead of HttpsConnection but i have changed this now but still no luck - just an empty array.

Comment: is there any chance i can have a look at your php implementation to make sure im doing it properly ?

Comment: I copied and pasted the PHP implementation directly from the Facebook docs listed in my first answer :-).  Have you tried using `curl` or a similar tool to first get your POST working?  That way you can start to isolate where the problem is?  Could be in your URL, POST data, or in your code.

Comment: Your  link to Simon Coss graph explorer has quickly been added to favourites but for this i cant seem to think off a way to utilise this tool to test a multi part post. But thank you.

Comment: Do you have access to the `curl` command?  [This](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html) explains how to POST a multipart form using `curl`.  If not, then how about the [Tamper Firefox plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tamper-data/)?  The point is to get your POST working outside of your code first.

Comment: Hi all, still struggling with getting a video accepted by facebook graph api. I have got the code to a point where it  is able to write the boundary message and then the video file. The graph api is telling me it cant find the video file though. A #353 error message. Please if anyway can give me a pointer i'd really appreciate it as this has swallowed the last 36 hours of my life!

Comment: Video needs some processing time on FB side.  When you posted the video did you get json back with the new id?  If so, try again with that id now and see if the video is there now.